# ReactJs How to dynamically render components based on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components

I have been asked to solve a problem using any front-end framework ( reactjs in my case ) . Basically there is a form for adding a car and there can be say a type of car like 'SUV','semitruck','racecar' and so on...

In the form there needs to be different components rendered based on the type of car you want to add ( e.g. SUV has 2 inputs , racecar has 5 inputs ) how can i dynamically render these components and get their input values without doing if statements?

So pretty much i want to avoid doing this :

```
{typeSelection == "SUV" && (
              <SVUInput
                size={sizeInput}
                changeSize={(str) => setSizeInput(str)}
              />
            )}
            {typeSelection == "Bus" && (
              <WeightInput
                Weight={weightInput}
                changeWeight={(str) => setWeightInput(str)}
              />
            )}
            {typeSelection == "Semitruck" && (
              <DimensionInput
                wheels={wheels}
                length={length}
                changeWheels={(n) => setWheels(n)}
                changeLength={(str) => setLength(str)}
              />
            )}
```

I tried doing this but doesnt work ( im guessing react doesnt re-render here )

```
  const [dynamicInputs, setDynamicInputs] = React.useState<any>({
    SUV: <SUVInput size={sizeInput} changeSize={(str) => setSizeInput(str)} />,
    bus: <BusInput weight={weightInput} changeSize={(n) => setSizeInput(n)} />,
    semitruck: <SemitruckInput wheels={wheelsInput} changeWheels={(n) => setWheelsInput(n)}
    color={colorInput} changeColor={(n) => setColorInput(n)} />,
  });
```

Instead the above code although renders the component , the input does not change when i type into it, it remains blank , i assume it doesnt trigger react to re-render the state

So pretty much instead of making many if statements that would slow down the front-end , Im trying to  make it dynamic so that it only takes O(1) time to render the correct form inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pretty like your solution because that's the thing I'm used to do really often. Your issue is about storing the components inside `useState`, because they are initialized there when component mounts and they just stay in the same state for the whole component lifetime. The solution is pretty simple as well - just move it out of the state so they do *react* to *state* and *props* changes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wozniak-xcy2bv?file=/src/App.js:114-536

```
export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
  const [currentComponent] = useState('SUV');
  const components = {
    SUV: <SuvComponent size={size} />,
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)} />
      {components[currentComponent]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It also works with UseEffect

Comment: @JustDankas Yes, it might work, but this is super hacky and crazy a bit - to update whole object and whole row with component with new data. Moving it out of the state you dont have to worry about that.

Comment: Yes i tried your method but typescipt yells at me and i dont know what to do , it says this ----->  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ SUV: Element; bus: Element; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ SUV: Element; bus: Element; }'.

Comment: @JustDankas Agreed, typings for such object with different components as values may be tricky. But it's not impossible, you would have to make a type with specified keys ('SUV' etc) and as values - `React.FC<SuvProps>`. Anyways I think it's a bit out of the scope of this question - please add a new one if needed, Im sure someone will help :)

Comment: thank you for all the help , have a good one

Answer (score 0):

it works if i implement the UseState method and then have a useEffect to update it like so :

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDynamicInputs({
      SUV: (
        <SUV size={sizeInput} changeSize={(str) => setSizeInput(str)} />
      ),
      bus: (
        <WeightInput
          Weight={weightInput}
          changeWeight={(str) => setWeightInput(str)}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, [dynamicInputs]);
```